# How is Bitmap.Options.inSampleSize supposed to work?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-6.0-marshmallow

An initial code was official doc: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap).

I've started poking around and found that images don't resize as described in a [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize):

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

When I've run a code:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "orig img size " + options.outWidth + "x" + 
          options.outHeight);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    // options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;  // version 2
    for (int i = 2; i<20; i*=2) {
        options.inSampleSize = i;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "inSampleSize: " + options.inSampleSize);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "img size "+options.outWidth+"x"+options.outHeight);
        if (b != null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "real img size " + b.getWidth() + "x" +
                  b.getHeight() + " byte count " + b.getByteCount());
            b.recycle();
        }
    }
```

Logs from running the code (Nexus 5, Android 6.0):

```
E/t: view size 1080x1776
E/t: orig img size 2448x3264
D/t: inSampleSize: 2
E/t: img size 1224x1632
D/t: inSampleSize: 4
E/t: img size 612x816
D/t: inSampleSize: 8
E/t: img size 306x408
D/t: inSampleSize: 16
E/t: img size 153x204
D/t: inSampleSize: 32
E/t: img size 228x306
E/t: real img size 228x306 byte count 279072
```

That's good, and now with a real load of files (`inJustDecodeBounds=false`):

```
E/t: view size 1080x1776
E/t: orig img size 2448x3264
D/t: inSampleSize: 2
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 71912460 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 62MB until OOM"
D/t: inSampleSize: 4
E/t: img size 1836x2448
E/t: real img size 1836x2448 byte count 17978112
D/t: inSampleSize: 8
E/t: img size 918x1224
E/t: real img size 918x1224 byte count 4494528
D/t: inSampleSize: 16
E/t: img size 459x612
E/t: real img size 459x612 byte count 1123632
D/t: inSampleSize: 32
E/t: img size 228x306
E/t: real img size 228x306 byte count 279072
```

I'm completely puzzled. If you look at byte count numbers, you may notice, that

Comment: Your resource is probably in a density-specific directory, and so the density conversions are also being taken into account. If you are bothering with `inSampleSize` with a resource (which itself is a bit odd IMHO), move the resource into `drawable/no-dpi/` or `assets/` or something that does not tie into density.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right. My resource was in `res/drawable`. I've moved it to `res/drawable-nodpi` and no it works just fine.

Where should I look to learn about the magic behind the density?
Why does it give different sizes depending on `inJustDecodeBounds`? I mean it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that there is a vision behind why `BitmapFactory` has a `decodeResource()` method. I have not yet quite figured out what that vision is.

Regardless, using `decodeResource()` does not eliminate the density conversion of any density-specific resources that you have. So, if you are on an `-hdpi` device, and the best-match edition of your drawable is in `res/drawable-mdpi/`, `inSampleSize` and the density conversion will both occur. And, frankly, I haven't spent the time to try to figure out exactly how those combine.

IMHO, if you are going to use `decodeResource()`, it should be for something that is not tied to a specific density: put it in `res/drawable-nodpi/`. But, that's just me.

> Where should I look to learn about the magic behind the density?

In general? There is [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) and [the other documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Specifically with respect to `BitmapFactory`? I am not aware of anything written about that.

> Why does it give different sizes depending on `inJustDecodeBounds`?

No clue, sorry.